# Menu Bar not appearing on Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, menu

I'm new to Tkinter and currently am learning from videos, I'm trying to create a menu bar with a further drop-down menu with some options and a separator, they won't have any function as I'm just trying to achieve that goal before adding onto it.
Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *


def donothing():
    print('Done')


root = Tk()

menuTop = Menu(root)  # this is a blank menu bar at the top
root.config(menu=menuTop)  # configures the menu feature, and assigns it to the Menu value

submenuDown = Menu(menuTop)  # this is a meta menu that *will* drop down
menuTop.add_cascade(label='File', menu=subMenu)  # assigns drop down menu to submenu def
submenuDown.add_command(label='Yes...', command=donothing)
submenuDown.add_command(label='No...', command=donothing)
submenuDown.add_seperator()
submenuDown.add_command(label='Exit!', command=donothing)

editMenu = Menu(menuTop)
menu.add_cascade(label='Edit', menu=editMenu)
editMenu.add_command(label='Redo', command=donothing)

root.mainloop()
```

When I run the code I get a blank window, I'm copying from a video which shows the code working as shown.
[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSm-tq5M-Dc&t=699s) is the video I am watching. I've tried putting it in a class but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you running on a Macintosh? On OSX the menubar appears at the top of the screen like any other app, not at the top of the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are mostly reference errors.

Line 14: you have referenced a name which does not exist:

```
menuTop.add_cascade(label='File', menu=subMenu)
# Should be ----------------------menu=submenuDown
```

Line 17: spelling error:

```
submenuDown.add_seperator()
# Should be -------a
```

Line 21: reference error:

```
menu.add_cascade(label='Edit', menu=editMenu)
menuTop ------- should be
```

After these changes it runs fine:

```
from tkinter import *

def donothing():
    print('Done')

root = Tk()

menuTop = Menu(root)  # this is a blank menu bar at the top
root.config(menu=menuTop)  # configures the menu feature, and assigns it to the Menu value

submenuDown = Menu(menuTop)  # this is a meta menu that *will* drop down
menuTop.add_cascade(label='File', menu=submenuDown)  # assigns drop down menu to submenu def
submenuDown.add_command(label='Yes...', command=donothing)
submenuDown.add_command(label='No...', command=donothing)
submenuDown.add_separator()
submenuDown.add_command(label='Exit!', command=donothing)

editMenu = Menu(menuTop)
menuTop.add_cascade(label='Edit', menu=editMenu)
editMenu.add_command(label='Redo', command=donothing)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Code runs well now, thank you very much. Not sure how I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code for a simple drop down menu

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.title('Drop down menu')
root.geometry('400x400')

def show():
    mylbl= Label(root,text=clicked.get()).pack()

options =[
    'monday',
    'tuesday',
    'wednesday',
    'thursday',
    'friday',
    'satarday',
    'sunday'
]

clicked =StringVar()

drop =OptionMenu(root,clicked,*options).pack()


root.mainloop()
```

You can further add commands to each option in the menu